# Why does Sombra's Translocator only work sometimes?

Tags: overwatch-2

I've recently been trying to use Sombras translocator, but for some reason I will throw it down, go push out in a fight, and then try to teleport back only to find that it's no longer available. Is there a cooldown? Did someone destroy it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Did someone destroy it?

Yes. If enemy founds your translocator and if they know how it works, they will destroy it. You will be notified if it gets destroyed (I'd provide screenshot if I got one at sometime.). Or perhaps you might have hit destroy button (Defaulted to F on PC, idk about consoles).

Comment: Thank you for this clarification! Need to place my translocator in a better place haha

Comment: @CodyLePort Happy to help. Make sure to tick the check button if you think your problem is now solved, to let others know the question is now been solved.

Comment: Honestly, I think the game needs a better indicator that it's been destroyed; at the moment she swears and the cooldown indicator resets, but it's incredibly easy to miss.

Comment: If you're playing the English version, she says something that sounds like "Jeans!" and you'll get a popup that says translocator destroyed. Also, if you want tips on how to better place your translocator, I'd recommend watching Fitzyhere on youtube.